# How to get the ListView Item that was right clicked before opening the context menu

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView with a ContextMenu attached to it.
In the menu handler function I want to know, which item of the ListView was right clicked before the ContextMenu was shown.

How can I do that ?

I'm using WPF and C#

Answer (score 0):

**Add a handler to the ListView.ContextMenuOpening event:**

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="_myListView" />
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs code-behind:

```
this._myListView.ContextMenuOpening += this._myListView_ContextMenuOpening;
```

...

```
void _myListView_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    object selectedItem = this._myListView.SelectedItem;
    // do something with selectedItem...
}
```

Comment: it seems not to work properly if other items are selected too.

Comment: what have you tried? hint: foreach (var item in this._myListView.SelectedItems) { }

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `MouseRightButtonUp` handler to every `ListViewItem`.